# Windows 10 computer BSODs roughly once a week with no detectable boot drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, crash

**What is your parts list?**

So, I got [this PC] (https://www.bestbuy.com/site/cyberpowerpc-gamer-supreme-gaming-desktop-amd-ryzen-7-3700x-16gb-memory-amd-radeon-rx-5700-xt-1tb-ssd/6400453.p?skuId=6400453) last black friday. The only thing I have changed in is replacing the front fans and one of the radiator fans with Corsair LL120s and a lightning node pro.

The hardware specs I know off hand are it uses a ADATA SX6000LP 1tb NVME, a XFX AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT, an ASUS PRIME B550M-A AC mobo, and a APEVIA ATX-PR800W 800w 80 gold power supply.

**Describe your problem. List any error messages and symptoms. Be descriptive.**

Starting about a month after I got the PC the PC would randomly BSOD with different errors, usually "Unexpected Store Exception" or "WHEA uncorrectable error." However, sometimes I would just walk into the room to see the computer at the BIOS screen. After the computer restarts from the BSOD it restarts into BIOS as it can no longer detect the boot drive. This is always fixed by turning off the computer, letting it sit for 2 minutes, then turning the power back on. After turning it back on the PC will be perfectly fine for a week or two before another BSOD. There were one or two instances where there were 3 BSODs back to back, but usually it is good for a week.

This usually happens when the computer is doing lightweight tasks. It has crashed once while playing Borderlands 3, but most BSODs happen when the PC is idle, I am on Zoom, or webbrowsing.

**List anything you've done in attempt to diagnose or fix the problem.**

I have an ADATA SX600LP NVME ssd and I checked it's health with adata's drive health tool as well as crystaldiskinfo and both say the drive is 100% healthy.

I have tried several times to get Windows to produce a minidump, but Event Viewer shows the dump failed to be created due to an error.

I have run Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool and memtest86 and both detected no problems.

I've run sfc /scannow and /chckdisk and both showed no errors.

I have updated my graphics driver, bios, and every other driver I could think of.

I reseated the ram and the graphics card.

I have checked Event Viewer and the only Critical Error was related my HyperX Cloud II's, but I have tried replacing them and have crashed several times since and those Critical Errors are not present in the Event Viewer.

I have been monitoring my HW temps with HWMonitor. The SSD idles at 35-39C, the CPU at 40C, and the GPU at 58-60C. I haven't seen any part get anywhere near a critical temperature.

Troubleshooting has been incredibly difficult, because the time between BSODs is so high. I will try a fix, then have to wait a week or two before the next BSOD to find that the problem is still there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things I have found (using my experience to look for them).

**[I]** Windows 10 BSOD  WHEA uncorrectable error

[WHEA uncorrectible error](https://windowsreport.com/fix-whea_uncorrectable_error-windows-8-1/#:%7E:text=The%20WHEA%20uncorrectable%20error%20is,a%20problem%20with%20incompatible%20drivers.)

> The WHEA uncorrectable error is a BSOD error usually caused by a
> failing hard drive, a defective memory module, improperly seated CPU,
> or other hardware issues. But it also might just be a problem with
> incompatible drivers
>
> You said: I have updated my graphics driver, bios, and every other
> driver I could

**[2]** I would go the board manufacturer support site and find all drivers and update them. Add Network, Power, Firmware updates and everything else you can find.

**[3]** If Intel RST was installed, uninstall it, at least while you are troubleshooting.

**[4]** Have you any way to test the Power Supply?

**[5]** Check both CPU and GPU operating temperatures  (Real Temp works)

**[6]** Look in Windows Minidumps for any current minidump files. For an initial look, Nirsoft Blue Screen View works.

> I've run sfc /scannow

**[7]** Run DISM and SFC

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

That is a start for troubleshooting.